# How should I optimize following requirement in my application. Dealing mainly with asp.net 3.5, C#, File I/O, Threading and some other aspects as well

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, file-io

Scenario -

It is an simple application through which only single user ( NO Authentication Reqd.) uploads only excel 2003/2010 file one at a time and then two functions are called `Foo()` & `Goo()` one after other taking some data from that excel doing some string manipulation & numeric computation returning two different text files for same user to download.

Now my question is how can I optimize this. Performance has high preference. Also how can I use Threading between those two functions `Foo()` & `Goo()` ? Will that optimize my performance ?
What more tips & tweaks are needed to achieve maximum speed in overall process.

Comment: you don't give enough information... for example: the threading question can't be answered without knowing anything about possible dependencies/intereference between the 2 functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the results of `Goo` depend on anything done in `Foo`? Do either of the methods actually *change* the data in the Excel document? Do they need to use the Excel object model other than to extract data to start with?

If not, you *could*:

- Extract the data needed for `Foo`, then launch `Foo` in a separate thread
- Extract the data needed for `Goo` and then run `Goo` (in the current thread, as it's already separate)

However, I would look at the existing performance characteristics of your code first - which bits actually take the most time? For example, if accessing the spreadsheet is taking more time than `Foo` and `Goo`, you won't get much benefit from the threading, and you'll certainly end up with more complicated code. (I *think* the Office COM objects are effectively single-threaded.) If `Foo` and `Goo` are the bottleneck, have you run a profiler on your existing code to see if you can make it faster *without* threading?

Do you have performance *targets* already? How close are you to meeting those targets? Don't bother trying to make the code as fast as it can possibly be, when you've already got it to run as fast as you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

If Foo & Goo are not related, you could run them in two different threads making them run in parallel